# Align divs from different parent div at same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I am trying to align two divs at the same height where the divs are not a part of a row div.

```js
var divh = document.getElementById('copyTarget1').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('copyTarget2').style.height = divh + 'px';
```

```css
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/dPJ5r9gl3kK6ijoeP1IRsvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/EsvMC5un3kjyUhB9ZEPPwg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}


body {
    background: hsl(184,65%,49%);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font: 15px/1.4em;
}

pre {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #2fbe35;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
code {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono;
    color: #2fbe35;
}

blockquote {
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.content
{
 width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.column1   {
    width: 50%;
    height:auto;
    float: left;
}

.column2  {
    width: 50%;
 height:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" debug="true"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>HTML-CSS EDITOR</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Mephisto">
<link href="./main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/tuupola" title="Atom feed">
<script src="./jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="column1">
<h1>CSS EDITOR</h1>
<div>Replace Header Text Color: </div><input type="text" id='thebox1'>
<div>Replace Header Background Color: </div><input type="text" id='thebox2'>
<div>Replace Logo Section Background Color: </div><input type="text" id='thebox5'>
<div id="copyTarget1">
 <blockquote>
     <pre>
      <code>
#topsection {
 background-color: <b class="popup2" style="color:#fff;">#value </b>;
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 z-index:1;
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:0;
 color: <b class="popup1" style="color:#fff;">#value </b>;
}
   </code>
  </pre>
 </blockquote>
</div>
<button id="copyButton1">Copy</button><br><br>
</div>
<div class="column2">
<h1></h1>
<h1>HTML EDITOR</h1>
<div>Enter header section text: </div><input type="text" id='thebox3'>
<div>Enter image link: </div><input type="text" id='thebox4'>
<div id="copyTarget2">
 <blockquote>
     <pre>
      <code>
   <xmp>
<div id="topsection">
<div id="header1"></xmp><b class="popup3" style="color:#fff;">HEADER TEXT</b><xmp></div>
<div id="header2">1 Jan 2015 - 31 Jan 2015</div>
</div>
</xmp>
   </code>
  </pre>
 </blockquote>
</div>
<button id="copyButton2">Copy</button><br><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Each div (`copyTarget1` and `copyTarget2`) are parts of 2 different columns that are aligned horizontally.

Now I am trying to align the two block quote boxes as shown in the image. In the future, I might alter the code and add more input boxes. So, I don't want to put a fix height for the two block quote boxes.

The idea was to use javascript but nothing changed. The link of the website is here : [LINK](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/HTML-CSS-EDITOR/index.html)
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: However, you should know that there is no CSS method to vertically align elments that do not share a parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know. That is why I tried using JS but it did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D I posted the code I used. The code snippet does not work for me as it says the code is too long.

Comment: A **minimal** demo is required...we don't need **all** the code, just enough to show the problem.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer i tried my javascript code and it worked please check it

Comment: @Paulie_D I added it. Although in the past I never had to post it. The problem here is in my JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the top of the blockquote section you need to make the content **above** that the same height in both columns.

So we wrap that content in a div (perhaps with a class of `.top`) and the use JS/JQ to determine which `.top` element is tallest and apply that height to all `.top` divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var highestBox = 0;
  $('.top').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > highestBox) {
      highestBox = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  $('.top').height(highestBox);

});
```

```css
body {
  background: hsl(184, 65%, 49%);
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font: 15px/1.4em;
}
pre {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #2fbe35;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
code {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono;
  color: #2fbe35;
}
blockquote {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.column1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.column2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="column1">
    <div class="top">
      <h1>CSS EDITOR</h1>
      <div>Replace Header Text Color:</div>
      <input type="text" id='thebox1'>
      <div>Replace Header Background Color:</div>
      <input type="text" id='thebox2'>
      <div>Replace Logo Section Background Color:</div>
      <input type="text" id='thebox5'>
    </div>
    <div id="copyTarget1">
      <blockquote>
        <pre>
      <code>
#topsection {
 background-color: <b class="popup2" style="color:#fff;">#value </b>;
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 z-index:1;
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:0;
 color: <b class="popup1" style="color:#fff;">#value </b>;
}
   </code>
  </pre>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <button id="copyButton1">Copy</button>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="top">

      <h1>HTML EDITOR</h1>
      <div>Enter header section text:</div>
      <input type="text" id='thebox3'>
      <div>Enter image link:</div>
      <input type="text" id='thebox4'>
    </div>
    <div id="copyTarget2">
      <blockquote>
        <pre>
      <code>
   <xmp>
<div id="topsection">
<div id="header1"></xmp><b class="popup3" style="color:#fff;">HEADER TEXT</b><xmp></div>
<div id="header2">1 Jan 2015 - 31 Jan 2015</div>
</div>
</xmp>
   </code>
  </pre>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <button id="copyButton2">Copy</button>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Codepen Demo**

*If you wish to make all the blockquotes the same height you could so that too.*

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I did not post a snippet in the beginning and I got a downvote :P Usually, I am getting an error that I exceeded the character limit so I am not using it too often.

Answer (score 1):

at line 10 you are missing:

```
</script>
```

use your console to check for errors

Comment: Thanx. That did not cause any problems though. I changed it anyway as it has to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change the height of `#copyTarget2` element

```
var divh = document.getElementById('copyTarget1').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('copyTarget2').style.height = divh + 'px';
```

Also you should give the background to this div not the `<pre>` tag to give the black background to the hole div

Also the `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">` doesn't have a closing `</script>` tag at line 10

Here are the screenshots where you can see that both divs `#copyTarget2` and `#copyTarget1` have the same height `255px`

CopyTarget1 http://prntscr.com/c6tvxf

CopyTarget2 http://prntscr.com/c6tw8n

Script http://prntscr.com/c6twb5

Comment: It did not work :( It aligns the text from the two divs though.

Comment: It works but like i said the background is not in div it's to <pre> element. i will post a screen shot there so you can see that height is actually same as other div